# How to use vbr mode to encode H264 using ffmpeg C library?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, encode, h.264

Recently I use ffmpeg C library to process my video. My src video is encoded with variable bit rate. I want my output video has similar quality and similar size. So I use following code to init my output context.

```
    outCodecCtx->width = pCodecCtx->width;
    outCodecCtx->height = pCodecCtx->height;
    outCodecCtx->color_range = pCodecCtx->color_range;
    outCodecCtx->pix_fmt = pCodecCtx->pix_fmt;
    outCodecCtx->time_base = pCodecCtx->time_base;
    outCodecCtx->framerate = pCodecCtx->framerate;
    outCodecCtx->bit_rate = pCodecCtx->bit_rate;
    outCodecCtx->max_b_frames = pCodecCtx->max_b_frames;
    outCodecCtx->codec_id = pCodecCtx->codec_id;
    outCodecCtx->codec_type = pCodecCtx->codec_type;
    outCodecCtx->gop_size = pCodecCtx->gop_size;
    outCodecCtx->profile = pCodecCtx->profile;
    outCodecCtx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
```

Here `outCodecCtx` is a `AVCodecContext*` for my output video, `pCodecCtx` is a `AVCodecContext*` for my src video.

However, the value of `pCodecCtx->bit_rate` is the average bit rate. As a result, the output video has a very low quality. I try to set a higher bit rate or use crf.

```
outCodecCtx->bit_rate = 2000000;
// or
// av_dict_set(&dic, "crf", "28", 0);
```

The quality is ok but the file size is so large. Maybe I can use vbr to keep similar quality and similar size? Or is there any way to do this?

BTW, some params of my src video:

- 1920 x 1080
- variable bit rate, avg: 330k, max: 1000k
- file size: 1.28MB, 00:00:27

My output video:

- 1920 x 1080
- constant bit rate: 2000k
- file size: 1.6MB, 00:00:05

Comment: Set CRF.........

Comment: @Gyan maybe I can set a large value for crf to keep a small file size. But I will use my program to process other videos. It's not a good idea to change crf for each video.